# A problem with aligning three elements horizontally, where the middle element grows to take up available space

Tags: css, display

My goal is to horizontally align three elements, where the middle element is an `<hr>` that takes up all available space(`width: 100%`) pushing the outer two elements to the sides.

The result would be like this: `AAA-------BBB`, where the `<hr>` element is represented with the hyphens.

### What I've tried

I've experimented with `display: inline-block` but with no luck.

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #777;
}

hr {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>AAA</h1>
  <hr />
  <article>
    <p>BBB</p>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: For future reference, the problem is the default display properties, in this case from div child elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to go about this is to use CSS Flexbox. The guys at CSS Tricks have a [really good guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) on the technology.

> A Complete Guide to Flexbox by Chris Coyier
>
> > `flex-grow`: This defines the ability for a flex item to grow if necessary. It accepts a unitless value that serves as a proportion.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  background: #777;
}

hr {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>AAA</h1>
  <hr />
  <article>
    <p>BBB</p>
  </article>
</div>
```

The `display: inline-block` property won't work as it's an inline element that you want to expand to 100% width of the **container**, not 100% of the **available space**. I hope this clarifies any confusion.

Comment: Hi there, I know about flex, I was trying to understand the inline-block property.

Comment: I've added an explanation in my answer, I hope that helps.

Comment: but even without width 100% on hr, it still don't go inline with the others elements.

Comment: It won't do that anyway, as paragraphs and headings are `display: block` by default. If you set the paragraphs and heading to `display: inline` everything will move to one line, similar to if all of the elements were inline elements.

Comment: oh that's it, so the problem was default style from the div child elements.
Now hr is a vertical bar haha, anyways that's another problem, Thanks.